No such file or directory while running a python project using venv in windows operating system
I created a basic python project as practice just beginning to get around it using chatgpt
tried running it using following commands
C:\Users\Hello\Desktop\projects\1project180424>python -m venv project1

C:\Users\Hello\Desktop\projects\1project180424>project1\Scripts\activate

(project1) C:\Users\Hello\Desktop\projects\1project180424>python app.py
C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\Hello\\Desktop\\projects\\1project180424\\app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

folder structure
 1project180424
    app.py
    templates
       about.html
       base.html
       home.html
       projects.html

app.py:
`from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')

@app.route('/projects')
def projects():
    return render_template('projects.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)`

home.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Home - My Profile{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Resume</h1>
<!-- Add your dummy resume content here -->
{% endblock %}


base.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{% block title %}My Profile{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Home</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/projects">Projects</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container mt-5">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


In the same directory where you ran python app.py, run the dir command and show us the output.

C:\Users\Hello\Desktop\projects\1project180424>dir
Volume in drive C has no label.
Volume Serial Number is B2B2-F79E
Directory of C:\Users\Hello\Desktop\projects\1project180424
18-04-2024  22:56              .
18-04-2024  22:56              ..
18-04-2024  22:52               364 app.p.py
18-04-2024  22:56              project1
18-04-2024  22:54              templates
1 File(s)            364 bytes
4 Dir(s)  10,983,968,768 bytes free
C:\Users\Hello\Desktop\projects\1project180424>

According to that output, the actual name of the file is app.p.py, not app.py.

feel like an idiot thanks man
